# What do the JHipster sub-generator phases do?

Tags: jhipster, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Recently, I've been trying to implement a blueprint for JHipster. I decided to override the entity and entity-server sub-generators. Each sub-generator has multiple phases of which I can choose to /totally override/partially override/not override/. The phases are :

/ initializing() / prompting() / configuring() / default() / writing() / install() / end() /

I got a vague understanding of what a couple phases do because of the name, but even then it's still not clear enough. I did not find any documentation on sub-generator phases anywhere. Can somebody tell me what is each phase's **exact** purpose?

If there is documentation on the subject that I didn't find, please link it to me!

Comment: I doubt you'll get an answer here, you'd probably get more help from opening a github issue. Are these phases jhipster-specific or do they come from yeoman?

Comment: That was my first thought, except there is a message on the generator-jhipster github saying "If you have a question, please use StackOverflow! [...] We primarily use GitHub as an issue tracker, if your issue is not a bug or feature request then sorry you are not in the right place .". TBH, i don't know whether phases are JHipster specific or Yeoman specific since I can't find anything on the subject.

Comment: Personally, I think that lack of documentation about generator's internals is an issue that could be opened on github. Your question is just an aspect of it.

Comment: It was indeed more of a Yeoman-specific question. I found something, which I will put as the answer for the question for now.  I might come back to add to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jhipster follows Yeoman priorities

link: https://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html#the-run-loop

The available priorities are (in running order):

```
initializing - Your initialization methods (checking current project state, getting configs, etc)
prompting - Where you prompt users for options (where you’d call this.prompt())
configuring - Saving configurations and configure the project (creating .editorconfig files and other metadata files)
default - If the method name doesn’t match a priority, it will be pushed to this group.
writing - Where you write the generator specific files (routes, controllers, etc)
install - Where installations are run (npm, bower)
end - Called last, cleanup, say good bye, etc
```

Comment: I've seen that latest JHipster has other priorities (or something like priorities), such as: PREPARING_PRIORITY, LOADING_PRIORITY, POST_WRITING_PRIORITY ... I believe this is specific to Jhipster. Where could we find something about them?